# Does an AWS CLI "Access Denied" error mean bad permissions or a bad key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I installed the aws command line client on my Mac High Sierra system.  I set the credentials and region using

```
aws configure
```

However, when I attempt to see any contents or specific bucket contents, I get "Access Denied" ...

```
localhost:tmp davea$ aws s3 ls 

An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.



localhost:tmp davea$ aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket-us

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

Does this mean my key/secret is wrong or just that the admin hasn't given me permissions to perform these actions?

Comment: You might want to try generating a new set of keys and configuring them in your `~/.aws/config` file, then try again.

Comment: Hi @BenWhaley, I'm unable to generate new keys -- these are what I was given.

Comment: Can you check the date & time on your computer, to see whether it is accurate? If the clock is too far "wrong", the requests will be denied.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the configured credentials are accessible by the command line by calling

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

If the identity is what is expected, and if you are using a session token, you should try setting it again in the *config* file.